# Where can I find source code for the Java data structures?

Tags: java, data-structures

Not sure if this has been asked before, did some digging.  I'm trying to prepare for a few interviews, and I was just curious to see if how Java implements its data structures (arraylist, map), etc is public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get [latest source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/c56b9022a4f3/src/share/classes/java/util/) from the **JDK7** repository. (JDK 6 is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools).)

Answer (score 10):

`src.zip` inside the JDK.

Comment: Finding the 'src.jar' file on Mac OS X can be tricky in recent years (2010-2011). See these two related questions for answers: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-version-1-6-0-22), and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011002/java-eclipse-on-macosx-where-is-the-src-zip).

Answer (score 3):

Use a modern IDE (like eclipse), link the locally installed Java SDK to a Java Project and you can view the source code of (most) classes from the SUN Java development kit.

Extracting src.zip is an alternative but it .. say .. doesn't support code browsing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Either src.zip, as suggested, or you can open them in your IDE (Eclipse for example), if you have set it up to use JDK.