# Source code for Mac OS X Java Updates

Tags: java, macos

Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3 upgraded to java 1.6.0_22. However, they did not include the source code or JavaDoc. Does anyone know if Apple provides the source, and if so, where to find it?

I'd like to attach the source to Eclipse.

Comment: This link helped me. http://koehnlein.blogspot.com/2011/03/jdk-source-code-on-macosx.html

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had the same problem today - I installed the Java Developer package from http://connect.apple.com, but couldn't find "src.jar" in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/...` anymore. On my machine, it's now
in
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`.

**Update:** For the latest version from March 2011, the jar is now:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`

Once again, you'll have to download the new Java Developer package first.

Comment: Source was in the same location on my machine as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is only available after downloading the Java Developer Package from http://developer.apple.com/java/download

Comment: Best to navigate to  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar using a terminal shell as you can't easily get to it using Finder.

Comment: yeah you can't view the source without the jdp download, but there is still more work to do after that.  eclipse won't let you navigate to the src.jar as an external archive, so you have to create a symbolic link and then edit source path to point to the symbolic link. The suggestion by Steve kind of shows you how to do that.

Comment: @Adrian: That isn't absolutely necessary. In OSX file browser dialogs, it's possible to enter a path directly: Just hit "/", and start typing the path. Enter `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk`, and once you're in that directory, you can browse as usual.

Comment: I had trouble with most of the apple.com links listed here. What finally worked for me was: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/downloads

Comment: And where is it with Snow Leopard (Feb 2012) ?

Comment: I had to go http://connect.apple.com/ to get the Java Developer Package

Answer (score 18):

What I do is as follows:

Download and install the Java Developer Kit (using your developer AppleId), current version `1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk`, and then in a shell, cd to the `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` directory.

Put in symbolic links to the jdk source files, `src.jar`, `docs.jar` and `appledocs.jar`, in the jdk you've just downloaded, that is:

`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar src.jar`

and similarly for the other two jars.

Then, in **Eclipse/Preferences**, you can create a new **Installed JRE** by *duplicating* the existing one (the existing one points to something like `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`) and then select the new **Installed JRE** and remove the original.

The Eclipse Projects might need updating to point to the 'new' JRE, but the source and javadocs should now be available for the standard java stuff without further ado.

**NB** Ensure that the version of the jdk matches the version of your system Java for this to work properly.

Comment: This still works, _mutis mutandis_, for the current JDK `1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk` from Apple. [Apple developer download site.](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

Answer (score 13):

Install java source, docs in 8 steps:

1. **Sign in with your Apple ID** (http://connect.apple.com)
2. Go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
3. Download **Java for OS X 2012-00* Developer Package**
4. Install **javadeveloper_for_os_x_ * .dmg**.
5. Go to **Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE**
6. Click **Search...**
7. Choose JRE with location like **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`1.6.0_your_jdk_filename.jdk`/contents/home**. In my case jdk file name was `1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk`.

   You can find the file name of jdk in terminal: `ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
8. Now, when you try "open declaration" and get message "Source Not Found" press button **Attach source...** and paste  **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`1.6.0_your_jdk_filename.jdk`/contents/home/src.jar**

Answer (score 11):

These are the exact steps that worked for me.

Go to the [apple dev java downloads page](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.10.3.3.1) and get the latest one you can (the apple dev web site will not let you download packages that are unsuitable for your OS version).
I installed [Java Developer Package for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 5 (Disk Image)](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/download?path=/Java/java_for_mac_os_x_10.6_update_5_developer_package/javadeveloper_for_mac_os_x_10.6__10m3425.dmg&wosid=ZV5zq2sfe40l3few5dYMfXhDnqd).

Then I executed these commands:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/src.jar
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk/Contents/Home/docs.jar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/docs.jar
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk/Contents/Home/appledocs.jar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/appledocs.jar
```

Then I restarted Eclipse (I didn't have to create a new JRE).

Comment: I found that you can happily *download* the packages but you cannot install them.  If you want Java 1.5 (say, for development IDEs, like Eclipse) but the Developer Package for Mac OS X 1.5<etc> isn't suitable to install then you can try [Pacifist](http://download.cnet.com/Pacifist/3000-2094_4-10135915.html) to extract the jdk from it. I now have 1.6 as standard and 1.5 as a jdk option in Eclipse.  *With* all the correct sources.

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to install the Java Developer Update: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html

Comment: +1. These don't get shipped automagically anymore. You need to signup at connect.apple.com to get these downloads iirc. After that you should be able to find the src.jar in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.x.x/Home/src.jar`

Comment: Thanks - RTFM, I guess :). @ChristopheD, the source has moved to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar

Answer (score 1):

Found it also not working after download and installation. Using the directory didn't work either for me. This helped finally:

```
 sudo cp  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
```

and the linked it through eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solutions were not working for me (not sure what I am doing wrong), but I was able to see the source in Eclipse when I selected the directory of `src.jar` instead of specifying the actual jar.

Answer (score 0):

FYI; On a Macbook Pro 2008, however reinstalled from scratch with Lion and NetBeans 7.0.1, thus the package Java 10.7 update 1 (the latest release), the source and JavaDoc were luckily auto installed after downloading the developer package as described in this thread. All is well.

Answer (score 0):

On 31-Jan-2012, Apple posted the [Java for Mac OS X Developer Preview 11M3614+10M3614](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.1.3.3.1) on their developer site.

This is a version that includes source code, doc, etc. (i.e., everything a developer needs).

Answer (score 0):

For OSX 10.7 Lion running Java update 1, I found the sources to be in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar. As noted in the other answers, you will first need to download and install the Java Developer package from Apple before setting this directory in your IDE.

Comment: Update 3 for 2012 is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_31-b04-415.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar.

Answer (score -1):

Download ubuntu package from the following link, extract it (usr ar command i.e. ar -x *.deb),

copy src.zip file and save it.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/all/sun-java6-source/download