# How to view Java SE 6 source in Netbeans on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source code for Mac OS X java version 1.6.0_22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-version-1-6-0-22)

I've been developing a web app using Java EE 6. At work I'm using Netbeans on Windows 7. I always took it for granted that I could view the Java SE 6 source by, say, ctrl-clicking on `String` and seeing the code.

Recently I installed Netbeans on my macbook at home (Mac OS X 10.6.5) and downloaded the project. Everything's working fine, but I noticed I can't view the source of the standard java classes any more. All methods have the `throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");` in them.

What's missing that I need to install here?

**Update:** Okay, after reading [this discussion](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/where-is-JDK-source-kept-on-Mac-OSX-td3242748.html) I went to http://connect.apple.com/ and downloaded/installed *Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 5 Developer Package* (also had to update OSX to 10.6.8). However, I still can't view the source in Netbeans. How do I configure Netbeans so the Java SE 6 source is viewable?

**Update 2:** I've been using http://javasourcecode.org/ in the meantime, but it would still be better to view the source in Netbeans.

**Update 3:** it looks like if I go to `Tools->Java Platforms->Sources` I can choose the source to read from. I tried selecting `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk` but this didn't work, which I guess makes sense since this is the default platform.

I keep reading everywhere that I should find the `.jar` I need at `/Library/Java/Home/src.jar` but it isn't there. A Spotlight search for `src.jar` or `src.zip` turns up blank. Can someone please help me fill in the blanks here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this post: [Source code for Mac OS X Java Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-version-1-6-0-22) Not sure why I didn't find it earlier as I searched pretty extensively - must have used the wrong keywords.

Apparently it's now located at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`. My mistake was not opening the package contents of `1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk`.