# No Java source on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, java

I think my JDK is broken. I am on OS X 10.6.8.

I want to look in the sources when debugging in Eclipse, etc, but Eclipse can't find the sources, so I looked up the installed JREs and found this path with the title `JVM 1.6.0 (MacOS X Default)`

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
```

In Terminal I went to the directory `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` and executed `ls -al`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel  442  8 Sep 22:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408  8 Sep 22:46 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5  8 Sep 22:45 1.3 -> 1.3.1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 21 Jul  2009 1.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10  8 Sep 22:45 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340  8 Sep 22:46 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1  8 Sep 22:45 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59  8 Sep 22:45 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

So Eclipse already has the proper JDK linked.
Another test:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_26

$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac

$ ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep javac
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel          75  8 Sep 22:45 javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
```

So it all looks fine, but there is no rt.jar or src.jar Here is a screenshot:

[image: A screenshot showing the jars in the current JDK.]

So I try to reinstall it. I go to Apple's [website](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/downloads) and download this package: `Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 5 Developer Package`, file: `javadeveloper_for_mac_os_x_10.6__10m3425.dmg`.
The installation finished successfully, but it doesn't change anything.

I show the last modified files on my computer, these are only some java tools, located in `usr/share/java/Tools`

- Java VisualVM
- Jar Bundler
- Applet Launcher

There still is no rt.jar or src.jar in the java home directory.

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer here can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-version-1-6-0-22

Comment: I read this topic already and try it, but it didn't help :( @msandiford

Comment: @msandiford I found that the second answer was more helpful than the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOTE:  This answer is old and for Apple Java 6.  For Oracle Java you need to download the JDK as it includes src.zip.

---

The source is not included in the default Java download.  You need to additionally install the corresponding development package available from ADC.

In addition, Eclipse has not yet been taught how to find the src.zip file and the dialogue cannot look inside packages.

On my 10.7, the above mentioned installation put src.zip in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-383.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar

Comment: Try running `find /Library/Java -name 'src.jar'`

Comment: Oh nooo, I was in the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ folder but with Finder I could not get into the directory, it only works with the Terminal... thx a lot!

Comment: In Finder, right-click and choose "Show contents of package" (or similar, it is in your own language).

Answer (score 3):

From: http://lookfirst.com/2011/03/fix-missing-source-for-java-mac-os-x.html (adapt version #s and paths as needed)

1. Go to http://connect.apple.com and download Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 4 Developer Package
2. Install it.
3. Open a Terminal.app window
4. cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
5. sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar .
6. sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home/docs.jar .

Comment: @timaschew did you read the answer carefully? the last two lines show that the source has moved to a somewhat hidden new place. Have a poke aound in the Library folders suggested, for me it is:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-384.jdk/contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

To all the guys who's been suffering from searching the source code here and there for hours but finally get nothing.

For Eclipse to attach(imperfectly available for 1.6):
[jdk1.7.0_21_src_for_mac.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B758ryeeYYQYbTNhUEdBZUZSVlk/edit?usp=sharing)