# Where is the source for Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 10?

Tags: java, macos

Apple pushed out an update to their Mac OS X Java two days ago.  In the past, I've been able to go to http://connect.apple.com and download the corresponding Developer Package so that my IDE can once again associate the new version of Java with its source code.  (Many thanks to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-version-1-6-0-22).)

But I'm coming up empty this time.  There's no "Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 10 Developer Package" listed, and Google has no hits for `"1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk"`.  Is there a new place to find the source, or is this new version of Java source-identical to Update 9, or am I just out of luck until Apple gets around to publishing the new Developer Package?

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here or on http://apple.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Apple took a few extra days to release the Developer Package.  It's now at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action .

Answer (score -1):

Java JDK Installer download site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html

Java JRE Installer download site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7u7-downloads-1836441.html

The latest Java for Mac OS X should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the latest Java 6, not the latest Java 7.  The Oracle site refers you back to Apple for Java 6.