# How can I get the jdk source code on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos

It seems that Mac OS does not ship with Java souce code anywhere. I am running OS X 10.8.1.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120345/645270) help? (See comments as well)

Comment: I do not think windows ships with it as well for that matter.

Comment: Or linux. You can get a buildable source from OpenJDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source code for Mac OS X Java Updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120107/source-code-for-mac-os-x-java-updates)

Comment: @giorashc It's located in a src.zip folder in the base Java directory with every JDK installation. (For Windows, anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the javadeveloper_for_os_x on https://developer.apple.com. It is a dmg installation file, simply install it with several next clicks and then you will find the src in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_XX.jdk/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 2):

The OpenJDK source can be found at:

http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/

Comment: The link is broken now. :(